# Is it possible and safe to create a RamDisk on an existing EC2 instance? If possible, how to do that?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ramdisk

I have an **EC2** instance that currently hold our web site, and we are thinking about pointing our "**Temporary ASP.NET** Files" Compilation Folder to a **RamDisk** on **EC2**. 
Not sure if it's a good idea and couldn't find much info around.

Answer (score 0):

Ramdisks are normally used for speeding up access to commonly used files. In your case I would assume that speed is not an issue, but that you want to save space on your main drive. In this case I would use the instance storage from EC2 - in contrast to the EBS backed main storage, this one will be flushed on reboot.

[Here is a posting on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/386346/how-can-i-access-instance-storage-on-a-windows-ec2-instance-with-an-ebs-root-dev) that shows you how to mount the instance storage. Also have a look at [the instance storage in the AWS documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html). Then you would have to move your Temporary ASP.NET Files folder to one of the instance-backed disks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually what I'm looking for is speeding up the compilation time. we already use amazon storage for our large files. the main issue is compilation time takes too long once we deploy new things.